# Oracle Date query between and equals

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to execute below query,

```
select symbol,effdate,anrev,morev 
from perf_intra 
where effdate 
  between TO_DATE('01/11/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') 
      and TO_DATE('05/12/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') 
  and TO_CHAR(effdate,'dd/mm') = '31/03';
```

I have records which satisfies both the conditions. But query returns nothing, but when I tried the conditions separately it works.

Can anyone please help me to find the issue with my query.

---

**EDIT:**

Let me put my question in more clear way,
Lets consider this,

**Query**

```
select symbol,effdate,anrev,morev
from perf_intra
where effdate between TO_DATE('25/11/2013','dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE('05/12/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

**Sample Data**

```
BMA 25-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 12.3977 11.2296
BMA 26-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 12.4174 11.2468
BMA 27-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 12.3991 11.2307
BMA 29-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 12.3975 11.2294
BMA 02-DEC-13 12.00.00.000000000 AM 12.3631 11.1991
```

**Table Description**

```
 Name    Null Type              
---------------------
SYMBOL       VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) 
EFFDATE      TIMESTAMP(6)      
ANREV        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) 
MOREV        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) 
REVAL        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

**I want all the records whose effdate is (Mar 31) and between (25/11/2013) to (05/12/2014)**

Guys,

Following solution worked,

```
select symbol,effdate,anrev,morev 
from perf_intra 
where effdate between 
      TO_DATE('25/11/2013','dd/mm/yyyy') and 
      TO_DATE('05/12/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')  
  and EXTRACT(month FROM effdate)=3 
  and EXTRACT(day FROM effdate)=31
```

Thank you all

Comment: Could you upload a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: show some sample data that you expect to work.   It could be that the dates you're looking at match 5/12 but have a time component not being matched.  What are the results if you switch the last and to an OR (that would give us some sample data to consider)

Comment: Is this just a sketch?  Why not use `to_char(effdate,'yyyymmdd') in (20140331,20150331)`

Comment: or `WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM effdate)=3 and EXTRACT(day from effdate)=31`

Comment: If the query returns no rows, then you have no rows that match the conditions.  What is the data type of `effdate` ?

Comment: @Gordon - Well said!

Comment: Hi Gordon, It is "TIMESTAMP". I have records which satisfies both the conditions. I have updated my question, please look into it. Thanks

Comment: @xQbert - It worked. Thank You.**select symbol,effdate,anrev,morev from perf_intra where effdate between TO_DATE('25/11/2013','dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE('05/12/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') and EXTRACT(month FROM effdate)=3 and EXTRACT(day from effdate)=31**

Comment: @RaghavJM Not sure why this worked vs other queries but glad it helped.  Now I know...  your original query should have worked but you needed to change `and TO_CHAR(effdate,'dd/mm') = '31/03';` to `and TO_CHAR(effdate,'dd/mm') = '31/3';` drop the 0 on 03... or maybe not... `select to_char(TO_DATE('31/03/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm') from dual` shows the zero.... dunno...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `where` written in an easier to follow date format:

```
where effdate between date '2014-11-01' and date '2015-12-05' and
      TO_CHAR(effdate, 'mm-dd') = '03-31';
```

The only date that meets both conditions is '2015-03-31', so you might as well write:

```
where effdate = date '2015-03-31'
```

or perhaps:

```
where trunc(effdate) = date '2015-03-31'
```

My guess is that you have no rows where `effdate` is '2015-03-31'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question with details. Can you please look into it.

Comment: @RaghavJM . . . The dates in your proposed solution are different from the original dates.  You can have effective dates on 2014-03-31 but not on 2015-03-31, which appears to be the case in your data.   If you run the original query with the same dates, it should also return values.

Comment: Yes dates are different, but still my old query didn't work with the correct dates.